# Huge Integer keys in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, types, integer

I need to create a table with a key that is a 256 Bit hash number. Fast searching and retrieving is crucial, so I am wondering what data structure to use as key ?

One option would be a varchar[32], but I guess searching will be very slow. The stored data amount will be much higher than a numerical solution.

A second option would be two different decimal[16] integers and combine them into a compound key, but I am sceptical if that would have a faster search performance than option #1.

I googled that topic, but didn't find solutions; perhaps some third option ? Any hints appreciated.

Comment: if it's a hash, then it is no good for a primary key! Primary keys have to be unique, whereas hashes aren't by definition. What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: If your 256-bit hash value is the natural key, store it as the proper data type binary(32) and make that a primary key clustered index to maximize performance. Consider the comment from @MitchWheat about collisions, though. Also, [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) rather an guess and ask our opinions about performance.

Comment: @MitchWheat, thanks for the hint, but honestly: collisions on a 256 Bit hash ? No current hard drive holds so much data, that you and I would probably see a collision in such a table in our lifetime (and if really, in this case doesn't matter anyway). Of course you are right for small hash values.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks for the hint, binary I didn't have in mind, I will test all 3 options and measure the performance.

Comment: @MitchWheat, taking into account the birthday paradox, to have 50% probability to find a collision you "only" need to try 2^128 different values. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47809/why-havent-any-sha-256-collisions-been-found-yet

Comment: @Jesús López: good point. I was thinking 2^64 not 2^256

Answer (score 0):

It is good the `PRIMARY KEY` of a table to be surrogate key and a number if possible. Using ``` SMALLINT, ``INT ``` or `BIGINT` with `IDENTITY` applied. Using such definition:

```
[RowID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

will help you solving some common issues - most importantly, when new records are created they will be appended at the end of the last index page, so no page splitting/fragmentation on insert.

Additional column can be added - your hash value and you can create an index on it, to make searching by hash faster.

For example, I have a IP addresses table holding all addresses used in the application (basically addresses used by users to log in).

The table looks like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IPAddresses]
(
     [IPAddressID] BIGINT IDENTITY(10000,1) NOT NULL
    ,[IPAddress] VARBINARY(84) NOT NULL
    ,[IPAddressHash] VARBINARY(64) NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_IPAddresses] PRIMARY KEY
     (
        [IPAddressID] ASC
     )
    ,INDEX [IX_IPAddresses_IPAddressHash] 
    (
        [IPAddressHash] ASC
    )
)
GO
```

As the `IPAddress` is personal data, it should be encrypted. And as I want my data to be normalized and I do not want to have duplicated records, I need to check each time a user log in if the address exists - if not create one. I am doing this using the following routine:

[image]

Here, I am passing the address and calculating a hash by which I am searching. The original version was instead using hash, to decpryt all the values and search by the text, but for millions of IPs this was very slow and this routine is executing constantly. On the other hand, I am performing only inserts in this table and records are appended only - so there is no fragmentation at all.

So, my advice is:

1. use number column with identity as primary key
2. add the rest of the columns in your table
3. add hash column and build a hash by the column(s) used for searches
4. create index on this hash column
5. then when you need to search for a record use the hash, located the `PK` ID and then use the ID to extract the record